# using geo panda on python to create own map

Tags: geopandas

I am looking at creating my own new map using python and hence need to create my own csv. What is the format of the csv which needs to be used. I want to perform all operations possible on a map using geo pandas.

```
    _______________________________________
   |         |                             |
   |         |                             |
   |         |-----------------------------|
   |         |                             |
   |         |                             |
    ---------------------------------------
```

Comment: please update your question to include what you've already tried and where you actually run into problems.  As a general comment, there is no "csv"-format requirement (in general you can read in the data using any conventions you like). Also there's a lot of documentation out there on how to create maps in general... what "operations" are you talking about?

Comment: I want to create my own map and import it in python and create nodes and edges based on corordinates

Comment: yes I see that... but "creating a map" is a quite general question... plotting some datapoints on a map can be done with numerous packages (cartopy, leaflet, plotly, ... )  In my case, I'm the dev of EOmaps (https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) it contains an extensive documentation that should help you to get started.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.